# Viber chat API, developing a Viber chat app to support dark theme

Tags: api, themes, chat, messenger, viber

I use Viber because my most important contacts use it, and it provides pretty much everything I need except for one thing: A true dark theme.

I wish to make my own version of messenger app, connecting to Viber server, at first it only needs to send and receive messages (not bulk send to multiple people, just 1 to 1 conversation). But I can't seem to find an API for this anywhere, only a REST API for creating bots on Viber developer's page.

My question is: Is there a Viber chat API which supports send **and receive messages**? If there is not, is there a way to use the bot's REST API to achieve such function?

Thank you for your time, any help is much appreciated!